# Notifications about new chat messages

Tags: feature-request, chat, notifications

Please add notification about new messages of some chat in "Inbox". Something like to subscribe for new messages to know about them.

Now small chats (between several people) work as archives and commenting usually stops after it is moved to a chat because it is very inconvenient for all users to update a chat page many times without any notifications if it is not an extra interesting big chat with many people.

Maybe the best solution may be to display some sign that there are unread new messages in some chat where is subscription (without displaying these messages and number of them). And it is the easiest to implement.

This issue is about very small, not active chats with two users and rare messages - like one in several days. So it is better to get a rare notification than check too many times (opened tab is needed to be checked too).

**The source of this request**: after mods move a discussion into a chat, nobody replies there in my experience because others can't know about new messages and don't want to bookmark a chat page and check it many times as me (because such small chats are not important to bookmark them).

Comment: I would say it is better to add chat notifications into mobile app instead

Comment: As the mobile app is [kaput](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353133/why-did-the-stack-exchange-android-app-disappear-from-google-play-store), I'd say it would be a very useful feature. Other sites' have this feature, maybe just a small icon indicating new messages. No idea why all the down-votes. It's easy to implement and could be optional to users. Small chats would really benefit from this feature.

Answer (score 6):

No, that's definitely not wanted.

You're already notified about direct replies to any of your chat messages.

Also you can see if there are new messages in a chat if you keep the site open.

> Now the chats work as archives ...

That's not true, there are many chat rooms which are used for *eerm* chatting. The users of such chat rooms would be pretty annoyed to receive inbox notifications about any activity going on there.

Comment: > keep the site open --- only need to open a chat page (if no mentioning) - totally inconvenient and kills chats. OK - chats usually work as archives - if it is between two people. Not a problem about annoying - just make the ability to subscribe as it works on github.

Comment: @oleedd You obviously have misconceptions how chat works at SE sites. Thus you shouldn't ask feature requests for things you don't fully understand.

Comment: They usually don't work by this reason if not many people there.

Comment: What special in chats? They are just separated from main sites.

Comment: @oleedd I've got not the slightest idea what you're after.

Comment: Notifications about new chat messages (without mentioning) on main sites.

Comment: @oleedd As mentioned that's probably not what the majority of (chat) users would like.

Comment: What is bad in subscribing on new messages of some chat? How can you know about majority? Make a voting to know for sure

Comment: So if you have 10 chat rooms - is it normal to update all the 10 pages several times per day to see new messages? Really?

Comment: @oleedd The point of subscription is coming up here without being mentioned anytime before. But even with subscription I wouldn't be notified for any action in the chat room, I believe many others won't do so like me.

Comment: @oleedd _"So if you have 10 chat rooms - is it normal to update all the 10 pages several times per day to see new messages? "_ You just go there, and see if there wer messages added  lately. What's the problem?

Comment: No. I see them here in notification https://i.imgur.com/nnyuitU.png Moreover, I will see it on any SE site but it doesn't work for chats.

Comment: If subscription for news works in the world and becomes more and more popular, then it is probably an important and good thing.

Comment: @oleedd: "*So if you have 10 chat rooms*" What are you doing that you would need to be in 10 chat rooms?

Comment: @NicolBolas It is just an example about 10 chat rooms.

Comment: @oleedd: That's part of the point: what is going on where the standard solution (keep chat tabs open separately) is not adequate for you?

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm regularly in 15-20... but I leave them open all the time and can see activity in the browser tab. Not sure why refreshing is necessary.

Comment: I'm *about* that many. Across 2 servers. But I know all the dirty tricks ;p

Comment: OK. The problem is even not in all this. I am not too lazy to open chats after launching PC. But all commenting with me dies after moving messages to a chat by mods because no one wants to update them (or keep open) if the topic isn't extra interesting. So the problem isn't in me. And it happens with all small chats between two people.

Answer (score 3):

You get notifications for pings, but you're looking for a way to find out when something new has happened in one of these rooms even if no one pinged you.  You can achieve that result by favoriting the rooms you're interested in -- click on the star in the upper right column (if you're in the room) or in the top right corner of the room's "box" (if you're looking at the room in a list or on its info page).  Then you can go to the "favorites" tab in chat and see all your rooms *in order of recency of activity*, like this:

[image: screenshot]

(Please pardon the redacted entries; I couldn't get a clean shot with only public rooms.)

Comment: The goal is to see notifications on any topic SE site - without visiting the chat site. Seems that this will not work for that.

Comment: SE isn't going to add this to the inbox; it would be way too noisy, and it goes against the other uses of inbox (direct notifications,like pings, or *really* important things like elections).  This answer gives you another way to achieve your goal, at the cost of one extra browser tab.

Comment: Why it would be noisy if no one will get notifications initially? Only after subscription to some chat if a user need this - extra useful for rare messages in small chats which mods create. It has been working on github very well.

Answer (score 2):

Chat is *almost* patterned on IRC, only with persistent scrollback. In some busier rooms, you literally get dozens or hundreds of messages a day - and I suspect that checking to see what you last read all the time can get quickly tiring.

Also I don't think chat stores what you last read. It stores what you last *said*. If SE did what you need, they'd need to keep the read state of every user - some folks do do that (sometimes badly - like slack), or I guess it could be done locally.

That said, its going to be noise. Just sat "Bye!" or something clever, go off, and use the "go to my last message" functionality and you'll be back to where you left off.

Comment: That is why I changed the idea to subscribe to some chat. So 10 000 will not come. Or even to add an alert or some tick that there is something new in a chat without displaying new messages. What about this? Also, there is not about finding the last read message, but only about a notification that there is something new to open some chat.

Comment: It...sounds like this request is an attempt to make chat work more like Discord, where it *does* save your position, and starts there next time you open it.  Personally, I find that far more annoying; nobody has time to read through everything you missed on anything but the most minimal rooms, so skipping back to the end is the default action.

Comment: @fbueckert No, I haven't said about starting on the last position. Moreover, if you don't need these notifications, you will not subscribe to a chat. Anything else bad?

Comment: @oleedd The request is functionally the same.  Personally, I don't want my inbox flooded with the thousands of messages it would have; there's a much easier way to make this work.  Journeyman's suggestion, or just keeping the tab open works, too.  This isn't something that needs additional dev time, I feel.

Comment: heh, I was thinking about slack. Which tries to do this, and fails horribly in my experience. And honestly, I suspect there's few users with more time on chat then me....

Comment: @fbueckert You probably didn't read the update of the request several hours ago. It is better to make some sign about new messages (without displaying these messages). Moreover, if you don't need a chat - you will not subscribe. Really to keep site open if one message for several days? Will you really click that tab many times to check and see that no messages each time? It is extremely useful in this case.

Comment: @oleedd Put simply, I disagree with you.  We're going to have to agree to disagree.

Comment: @fbueckert So you like checking almost empty chats 10 times per day instead of getting a single notification about a rare message (after subscription)? This issue is about very small, not active chats with two users.

Comment: @fbueckert Read about the source of this request. It is a problem. Not a simple feature request. Do you have a solution? I could post this without any solutions but tried to come up with an idea and got many downvotes after. Find something better and it would be fine.